# How to show only populated menu tabs in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, tabs, usability, menu

In evaluating the [Invite](https://drupal.org/project/invite) and [Support](https://drupal.org/project/support) modules for Drupal recently, we realized the default tab navigation is not the most user friendly. In particular, each module has a page of tabs that show the various categories of invitations or support tickets (pending, cancelled, etc). For  developers, it's easiest to pre-define all the tabs, but from a user standpoint, it makes more sense to only be offered the tabs that contain content.

I assume it's possible to run queries to check which tabs should be displayed for a particular user and change the menus using [hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu_alter/6). However, is that the best way to do it or will that cause problems with Drupal's menu caching? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by jhedstrom is correct, but I'm not that convinced that dynamically showing/hiding local tasks results in better UX, that sounds kinda confusing to me.

Instead, my suggestion would be to use a title callback (which can be added with the same hook_menu_alter() and show the number of things inside that specific tab. That is what I for example use for Privatemsg to show the number of unread messages.

See [privatemsg_title_callback()](http://api.worldempire.ch/api/privatemsg/privatemsg.module/function/privatemsg_title_callback/6-2) for an example and [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) for more information about title callbacks in general.

Comment: Thanks, I like that idea! Funny, we're in the process of adding Privatemsg too, but I hadn't yet noticed that feature.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to selectively remove tabs in a dynamic way (eg, one node gets a tab, while another does not), you won't be able to use hook_menu_alter() because that only has an effect when the menu cache is being built. However, you can do this by overriding the menu access callback. If access to a tab is denied, it won't be displayed.

For example, to override a node tab, you might do something like this:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $item['node/%node/foo']['access callback'] = 'mymodule_override_access';
}

function mymodule_override_access($node) {
  // Perform queries, logic, etc to determine if content exists at node/nid/foo.
  // Return false if there is no content, otherwise fall through to the original
  // access callback function.
}
```